# Error in query: The multi-part identifier "XYZ" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, alias

Just a quick question..
I have following sql query which is throwing an error while executing. This query using inner join with single table. Please help, why would this throw an error on ON statement ?

```
SELECT OutOps.MachineId, OutOps.CBPOsVersion, OutOps.LastTimeStamp
FROM  CBPOperationStatsDaily AS OutOps
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(LastTimeStamp) , MachineId
    FROM CBPOperationStatsDaily AS InOps
    GROUP BY InOps.MachineID)
ON (InOps.LastTimeStamp=OutOps.LastTimeStamp)
```

EDIT: Added a missing parenthesis, still fails.

EDIT: Found the solution, sorry admins for not being precise about the problem.

**Resolution:**
Two mistakes, first was not naming the `MAX Column`, second was not using `InOps` incorrect in the `'ON' statement`. For `Join name(ON)`, the outer table alias was to be used, while for the `GROUP BY InOps` is to be used.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis after the inner query

Comment: Also, the table alias for `InOps` needs to come after the inner query. i.e. `INNER JOIN (...) AS InOps`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please note that SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: And, also, you have a typo in your last field. `OutPos` should probably be `OutOps`?

Comment: if your problem solve using answer, then mark as answer? @confusednerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the position of alias `InOps` for the joining table:

```
SELECT OutOps.MachineId, OutOps.CBPOsVersion, OutOps.LastTimeStamp FROM  CBPOperationStatsDaily AS OutOps INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(LastTimeStamp) as LastTimeStamp , MachineId
    FROM CBPOperationStatsDaily
    GROUP BY MachineID) as InOps ON (InOps.LastTimeStamp=OutOps.LastTimeStamp)
```

Comment: if you run this query, you got error   Incorrect syntax near '¨'.: SELECT OutOps.MachineId, OutOps.CBPOsVersion, OutPos.LastTimeStamp FROM CBPOperationStatsDaily AS OutOps INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(LastTimeStamp) , MachineId FROM CBPOperationStatsDaily GROUP BY MachineID) InOps ON (InOps.LastTimeStamp=OutOps.LastTimeStamp)¨

Comment: Just a little typo :) Fixed, thank you

Comment: you are using the wrong alias name in main query

Comment: Yea i just copied his version and fixed the real issue. Didnt see that he has also a typo mistakes there . Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are missing table alias for `InOps` for subsquery, and also for max(LastTimeStamp) column use the alias name

```
SELECT OutOps.MachineId, OutOps.CBPOsVersion, OutOps.LastTimeStamp
FROM  CBPOperationStatsDaily AS OutOps
INNER JOIN
    (  SELECT MAX(LastTimeStamp) as LTS , MachineId
       FROM CBPOperationStatsDaily
       GROUP BY MachineID) AS InOps
ON (InOps.LTS=OutOps.LastTimeStamp)
```